# Content appended twice in the CSV file when CSV is generated using PHP button

Tags: php, mysql, csv

This is my code to generate csv file.When I click php button to generate Csv file,which is filled withthe contents based on the category column from the database.But my problem here is when the contents are getting populated twice in the csv file as shown below.Please help to out where i have to modify the code so that i can get only one time populated content as shown below as expected.Thanks in advance.

createcsv.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stats";

define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "stats");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASSWORD", '');

$dbconn = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$conn = @mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$dbconn);


// Create connection
//$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "DB connection failed";
} 

// Query DB to fetch hit count for each category and in turn create corresponding .csv file
function createCSVFile($type) {
    $msql = "SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.000000' from UNIX_TIMESTAMP(hitdate)*1000) as unixdate,count from h_stats where category='".$type."' order by unixdate asc";

    $query = mysql_query($msql); 

    $type = str_replace(' ', '', $type);

    $tmp_file = "data/tmp_".$type.".csv";
    $fp = fopen("$tmp_file", "w");

    // Write the query contents to temp file
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
      fputcsv($fp, $row);

    }
    fclose($fp);

    // Modify the contents of the file as per the high chart input data format
    $fp = fopen("$tmp_file", 'r+');
    rewind($fp);
    $file = "data/".$type.".csv";


    $final = fopen("$file", 'w');

    while($line = fgets($fp)){
        trim($line);
        $line = '['.$line.'],';
        fputs($final,$line);
    }

    // Append var $type and remove the trailing ,
    $final = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = 'var '.$type .'= [' . rtrim($final, ","). ']';
    file_put_contents("$file",$content); 

}

// Query DB to fetch success/failure count for Hits and in turn create corresponding .csv file
function createHitOutcomeCSVFile($type,$category) {
    $sql = "SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '.000000' from UNIX_TIMESTAMP(hitdate)*1000) as unixdate,".$type." from h_stats where category='".$category."' order by unixdate asc";

    $query = mysql_query($sql); 

    $tmp_file = "data/tmp_".$type."_".$category.".csv";
    $fp = fopen("$tmp_file", "w");

    // Write the query contents to temp file
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    // Modify the contents of the file as per the high chart input data format
    $fp = fopen("$tmp_file", 'r+');
    rewind($fp);

    $category = str_replace(' ', '', $category);

    $file = "data/".$type."_".$category.".csv";

    $final = fopen("$file", 'w');

    while($line = fgets($fp)){
        trim($line);
        $line = '['.$line.'],';
        fputs($final,$line);
    }

    // Append var $type and remove the trailing ,
    $final = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = 'var '.$type.'_'.$category.'= [' . rtrim($final, ","). ']';
    file_put_contents("$file",$content); 

}
    // Invoke function to create the Hits.csv file
    createCSVFile('Hits');

    // Invoke function to get Three Hits csv file
    createHitOutcomeCSVFile('TCount','Hits');

    // Invoke function to get O2 Hits csv file
    createHitOutcomeCSVFile('BCount','Login');

    echo "Generated successfully";

?>
```

not expected csv file with twice populated data:

```
var Login_Hits= [[1427826600000,1427826600000,8763,8763
]]
```

Expected csv file as per highcharts format:

```
var Login_Hits= [[1427826600000,8763
]]
```

Comment: How is that connected to the Highcharts lib?

Comment: @Pawel Fus The Csv file format is Highcharts ones.So I have given Highcharts tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug it...
it will be easier than seeing typo or so...
it looks like the tmp file is already corrupted...
try to display the `$row` variable and the `$query`... 
the problem may come from here...

Comment: @ random  Yes as you said I have echoed it.It is coming from there only.but I have renamed it to $query1 and $row1 for the debug sake but im not getting it

Comment: Can you tell us what's their content please ? It would help ;)

Comment: @ random   In Csv file Im getting data repeated as follows: var Login_Hits= [[1427826600000,1427826600000,8763,8763
]]  instead of  var Login_Hits= [[1427826600000,8763
]] and Im getting  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource error

Comment: You also have this in your tmp file I guess ? but what about the content of your `$row` and `$query` ?

Comment: @ random  I have changed the function to mysql_fetch_assoc in while loop now it is working fine.Thanks for your response

Comment: Ok, please add the answer at the end of your post then, in order to help next visitors with same issue :)

Comment: @ random Added the changes

Answer (score 0):

In while loop I have used mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array at both the functions

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      fputcsv($fp, $row);

    }
```

The  content is not repeating twice in the Csv file.This works try it!